Use pipeThrough/pipeTo to transform then stream to Azure Blob
I'm trying to stream some data from an API, transform it, then upload to Azure blob using an Azure function. The limitation I face using Azure Blobstore is that there's no 'writeStream', only uploadStream. There's no obvious point in the pipeline to upload to a stream.
Example -
   function MyWriter(writer) {
      return new WritableStream({
        write(chunk) {
          console.log('writing');
          writer.write(chunk);
        },
      });
    }

    export const generate = async (iterable) => { 
      await ReadableStream.from(iterable);
        .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
        .pipeThrough(new MyTransformer())
        .pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'))
        .pipeTo(MyWriter(writeOutStream));

    /*. await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(); */
    }

Am i missing something obvious?
Azure upload stream docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-javascript#upload-a-block-blob-from-a-stream
Tried various combinations of pipelining, but there's no obvious point to upload the stream.

The link that you shared shows using an instance of Node.js Readable stream as an argument: await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(readableStream) — this is not an instance of WHATWG ReadableStream.

Ah, yeah, heh. Makes sense now.

Missed the type on the Azure docs. Use Readable.fromWeb to convert from ReadableStream to Readable to stream to Azure Blobstore, no write method needed.
  const readableStream = ReadableStream.from(myIterable);
        .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
        .pipeThrough(new MyTransformer())
        .pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));

  await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(
     Readable.fromWeb(readableStream),
     'blobbyBlobbyBlobby.xml.gz'
  );


If this is the answer, please [edit] with proper explanation and mark this answer as the correct answer. If this is an addition/update to your question, please delete this and edit your question instead with the updated info.
